# Is there a way to set Ubuntu user ID at installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, uid

The Ubuntu installation wizard includes a step to create a user with sudo rights. By default this user is assigned UID=1000  Is there a way to override this, in that wizard step?

I know it's possible to change a user ID later, but for my scenario the above would be easier

Comment: Are you sure? `root` user in linux system has a id of `0` and you can't change it.

Comment: I've rephrased the question. I mean the user with sudo rights that is created in the wizard

Answer (score 1):

If you use preseeding, yes. From the [example preseed file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt):

```
# To create a normal user account.
#d-i passwd/user-fullname string Ubuntu User
#d-i passwd/username string ubuntu
# Normal user's password, either in clear text
#d-i passwd/user-password password insecure
#d-i passwd/user-password-again password insecure
# or encrypted using an MD5 hash.
#d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password [MD5 hash]
# Create the first user with the specified UID instead of the default.
#d-i passwd/user-uid string 1010
# The installer will warn about weak passwords. If you are sure you know
# what you're doing and want to override it, uncomment this.
#d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
```

As you can see, there's a preseed option: `passwd/user-uid`.

You can read more about preseeding in [the Ubuntu LTS installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html).